# Unable to deploy firebase functions from github action

Tags: firebase, docker, github, github-actions

I have seen similar questions to this but I have a specific use case here which maybe be of interest, I am receiving an error which obviously means `firebase-functions` is not being installed properly on docker container, everything work fine on local.

Entire deployment works perfect and file structure created in docker container looks right, with `node_modules` being placed in correct folder, everything.

Does docker need to be enabled to expose port to firebase deploy to get correct download? Anyone have experience with this?

Error

```
[2022-10-08T08:09:34.513Z] Building nodejs source
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.development. 
[2022-10-08T08:09:34.518Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
[2022-10-08T08:09:34.533Z] Error: spawn ./node_modules/.bin/firebase-functions ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

action.yml

```
deploy-cloud:
  name: Deploy Cloud
  needs: e2e-test
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '16'
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: docker://xxxxxx/create-envfile:master
      with:
        ...env vars...
        directory: functions
        file_name: .env.development
        fail_on_empty: false
    - name: Install Dependencies
      working-directory: functions
      run: yarn
    - name: Build
      working-directory: functions
      run: yarn build
    - name: Deploy to Firebase
      uses: docker://xxxxxx/firebase-action:master
      with:
        args: deploy --project development --only functions --debug
      env:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Dockerfile for deploy action

```
FROM node:16.16.0-buster

LABEL version="0.0.1"
LABEL repository="https://github.com/xxxxxx/firebase-action"
LABEL homepage="https://github.com/xxxxxx/firebase-action"
LABEL maintainer="xxxxxx"

LABEL com.github.actions.name="GitHub Action for Firebase"
LABEL com.github.actions.description="Wraps the firebase-tools CLI to enable common commands."
LABEL com.github.actions.icon="package"
LABEL com.github.actions.color="gray-dark"

RUN apt update && apt-get install -y jq openjdk-11-jre

RUN npm i -g npm@8.10.0
RUN npm i -g firebase-tools@11.8.0

COPY LICENSE README.md /
COPY "entrypoint.sh" "/entrypoint.sh"

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm downgrading to `firebase-tools` 10.0.0 fixes this issue